# InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Complete error message:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I get this error when I try to update user info on View page.

Updated code:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        //Get user and return the Edit View
        ApplicationViewModel model = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id)
      .Select(u => new ApplicationViewModel()
      {             
          UserName = u.UserName,
          ClearTextPassword = u.ClearTextPassword,            
          PhoneNumber = u.PhoneNumber,             
          Enabled = u.Enabled

            // Add the remainder properties
        }).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, ApplicationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
            return NotFound();

        user.UserName = model.UserName;
        user.ClearTextPassword = model.ClearTextPassword;
        user.Enabled = model.Enabled;
        user.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;

        {
            var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //db.Entry(listdata).State = EntityState.Modified;
                //db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

I expect the  user info to save to the database and show the change on the Home page after clicking Save button.

Comment: I don't see a difference between this code and the one in the answer. If you changed it, it makes sense for other people see the original wrong version, rather than the fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, this is why you should use view models. There's actually additional reasons besides just this one specific exception.

First, the explanation of what's happening. Somewhere in your codebase, during the processing of this request an instance of `ApplicationUser` with the same id as what you're attempting to edit was queried. This could have been caused by any number of different things: the important part is that your context is already tracking this particular instance.

When you bind the post directly to `ApplicationUser` here in your action, you're creating an entirely different instance. Adding that new instance directly to your context, attempts to start tracking that instance as well and fails because there's conflict with what your context is already tracking.

Two takeaways:

1. When editing an entity ALWAYS pull it fresh from the database, alter it as necessary, and then save *that* instance back to the database.
2. You should NEVER directly save anything created from the post (i.e. the `user` param of your action here) to your database. There's a whole host of reasons why you should not do this, but security is first and foremost. Post data is data from the user and NEVER trust the user.

Using a view model fixes both of these issue. You simply create a class like `ApplicationUserViewModel` (the name doesn't matter) and then add properties to that *only* for the data you want to allow the user to modify. In other words, you'd exclude things like an ID (IDs should ALWAYS come from the URL), created date and other audit trail stuff, etc. Then, you bind the post to this view model, pull the actual entity you want to modify from the database, map the relevant data onto that entity and then save that entity.

Added altogether, that would make your action look something like:

```
[HttpPost("{id}"]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, ApplicationUserViewModel model)
{            
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
        return NotFound();

    user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    user.LastName = model.LastName;
    // etc. You can also use a mapping library like AutoMapper instead

    var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        // db.Entry(listdata).State = EntityState.Modified;
        // db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I think this will work but I lost my Edit link url. It used to be localhost/editprofile/Edit. Now it is localhost/{id} and the link breaks. What do I need to do to get that link back?

Comment: You must have been using conventions-based routing. The default route will accept an id, so you can probably just change the attribute back to `[HttpPost]`. To stick with attribute-based routing, you'd simply need to apply something like `[Route("[controller]")]` to the controller class, and then `[HttpPost("edit/{id}")]`.

Comment: Now I get  an error 'InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'FE.Models.ApplicationViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'FE.Models.ApplicationUser'. I'm using ApplicationUser on the HttpGet for my Edit action. Updated code in OP.

Comment: The view model is what your view needs to be using as well.

Comment: I get the same error it just happens on the get instead of the post. This is what I changed the view to @model FE.Models.ApplicationViewModel. Does everything in the httpget need to change to ApplicationViewModel?

Comment: Dude. Yeah. You need to use your view model all the way through. Don't ever use your entity class for anything but back and forth to the DB. All views, should use the view model, and all actions should receive and/or return the view model.

Comment: Ok then how do I combine the httpget and httppost or do I? As you can see in my OP they are both using edit actions. If I use the view model how do I do that for both?

Comment: In the get action, you query your entity, map it to your view model, and return the view model to the view. In the post action you receive the view model, map it to your entity (pull fresh from the database) and save it back. The view in both cases uses the view model.

Comment: I  updated my code in OP, get error on Edit 'Type EditController already defines a member called 'Edit' with same param type'. I guess the get and post need to have different Edit actions? I don't get it because they were that way before.

Comment: I don't see anything in your updated code that would cause this. Perhaps you left the remnant of a previous version of these actions around? In any case, I noticed an error in my sample code that unfortunately may have caused some of the confusion. When I was modifying your existing code, I neglected to change the final return line. That should be returning `model`, not `user`. I've updated it in my sample.

Comment: Ah finally. Got this thing to work. Thank you so much for your help and being patient with me Chris.